# Is HWND visible?

Tags: c#, windows, hwnd

Those darned users and their minimized windows.

In C#, if I have a window's HWND, is there a way to tell if it is visible on the desktop?

Comment: We are all users, too, and who to you program for anyway if not for the users? By the time of this writing I have 5 minimized windows

Comment: The echos of sarcasm from five years past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`GetWindowPlacement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633518(VS.85).aspx) function returns a [`WINDOWPLACEMENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632611(VS.85).aspx) structure which has a field `showCmd`:

> Specifies the current show state of the window.

The details of this read as though you would be setting the window state, but I suspect that this is because they've been copied from somewhere else and not updated.

Comment: Phew thanks, spent at least 10 minutes of boring googling to find out how the heck one is supposed to check window visibility via WinAPI... The name is a little obscure and of course the documentation for how to hide a window doesn't link to it...

Answer (score 3):

There's the `Visible` property, but that checks the visible flag, it doesn't tell you whether the window is being covered by another window, or off the screen, etc..  That's a lot more tricky.  Raymond Chen has some tips, though:

- [Determining whether your window is covered](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030902-00/?p=42693)
- [Painting only when your window is visible on the screen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030829-00/?p=42743)

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isHwndVisible = Control.FromHandle(handle).Visible
```

Comment: That only works for (Managed) Controls in the current Application. I think the OP is referring to another application.